# Spring Oauth2 : How to get all clientIds?

Tags: spring-security, spring-oauth2

Has there anyway to retrieve all clientIds from `OAuth2Authentication` ?
I can get single clientId from `Oauth2Request` as

```
String clientId = auth.getOAuth2Request().getClientId();
```

but I'd like to know them all.

Comment: @dur I would like to retrieve not only current request's clientId but also all available clientIds these are approved for current authenticated user.

Comment: @dur Sorry , I forgot to mention it. Yes, I created my own authentication server and I have access to use `tokenStore` , `approvalStore` etc. I can fetch all clientIds with sql-query from `oauth_client_details` table or approved clientIds from `oauth_approvals` as described from [Schema for PostgreSQL to use with JdbcTokenStore](https://gist.github.com/fernandomantoan/3ff4b90d7e9eae4a5d1e) but I'm asking about has there any easy ways to achieved it without writing additional queries. Thanks

Comment: @TwiN No bro. (Google/Facebook/GitHub/...) perform as auth-server. I would like to see all client applications of autheticated user these are approved from my auth-server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client IDs are configured on the [authorization server](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.1) and there is no standard way to get the client IDs on resource server side.

Hence, if you use an external authorization server like Google, Facebook or GitHub you have to look into their APIs.

With your own authorization server, you could get all client IDs, see  [`ClientRegistrationService`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/ClientRegistrationService.html):

> Interface for client registration, handling add, update and remove of ClientDetails from an Authorization Server.

All you need is a [`ClientDetailsService`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/ClientDetailsService.html) implementing `ClientRegistrationService`, for example [`JdbcClientDetailsService`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/client/JdbcClientDetailsService.html).